Publishing a .net project with Nuke is not including the ClientApp folder
My Solution structure:
MyApp
│
├── MyApp.Client
│
└── MyApp.Server

I want to automate the publishing process into one command line argument. So when I run nuke --Environment Staging --Publish true it publishes my app. The problem is when I right click on my project and hit publish using my "Publish-Staging" profile then it works perfectly.
In my MyApp.Server.csproj I added
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="ClientApp\**">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

which makes it include this folder when publishing. MyApp.Client is my angular frontend, and when building it compiles into MyApp.Server/ClientApp/dist.
However when I run the nuke command my ClientApp folder is not published, even though I'm passing in the same "Publish-Staging" profile. There are no errors it all succeeds yet I'm missing my ClientApp. Sure enough my MyApp.Server/ClientApp/dist has all the correct files but none are included in the publish.
class Build : NukeBuild
{
    public static int Main() => Execute<Build>(x => x.Compile);

    [Parameter("Configuration to build - Default is 'Debug' (local) or 'Release' (server)")]
    readonly Configuration Configuration = IsLocalBuild ? Configuration.Debug : Configuration.Release;

    [Parameter("Environment")]
    readonly string Environment;

    [Parameter("Publish")]
    readonly bool Publish = false;

    [Parameter("Path to the Angular project")]
    readonly string AngularProjectPath = "MyApp.Client";

    [Parameter("Path to the .NET Core project")]
    readonly string DotNetProjectPath = "MyApp.Server/MyApp.Server.csproj";

    Target Clean => _ => _
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cleaning directories...");
            // Clean Angular build output directory
            if (Directory.Exists("MyApp.Server/ClientApp"))
            {
                Directory.Delete("MyApp.Server/ClientApp", true);
            }
            // Clean .NET build output directory
            if (Directory.Exists("MyApp.Server/bin"))
            {
                Directory.Delete("MyApp.Server/bin", true);
            }
            if (Directory.Exists("MyApp.Server/obj"))
            {
                Directory.Delete("MyApp.Server/obj", true);
            }
        });

    Target Restore => _ => _
        .DependsOn(Clean)
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Restoring dependencies...");
            // Restore .NET Core project dependencies
            DotNetRestore(s => s.SetProjectFile(DotNetProjectPath));

            // Restore Angular dependencies
            ProcessTasks.StartProcess("npm", "install", AngularProjectPath)
                .AssertZeroExitCode();
        });

    Target BuildAngular => _ => _
        .DependsOn(Restore)
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Building Angular project...");
            string env = Environment.ToLower(); // angular.json configurations are lower case.
            ProcessTasks.StartProcess("ng", $"build --configuration={env}", AngularProjectPath)
                .AssertZeroExitCode();
        });

    Target BuildDotNet => _ => _
        .DependsOn(BuildAngular)
        .OnlyWhenDynamic(() => !Publish)
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            // Build .NET Core project with the specified configuration
            Console.WriteLine("Building .NET Core project...");
            DotNetBuild(s => s
                .SetProjectFile(DotNetProjectPath)
                .SetConfiguration(Configuration)
                .SetProperty("Environment", Environment));
        });

    Target PublishMsBuild => _ => _
        .DependsOn(BuildDotNet)
        .OnlyWhenDynamic(() => Publish)
        .Executes(() =>
     {
         var publishProfile = $"Publish-{Environment}";

         MSBuildTasks.MSBuild(s => s
                     .SetProjectFile(DotNetProjectPath)
                     .SetConfiguration(Configuration)
                     .SetProperty("PublishProfile", publishProfile)
                     .SetTargets("Publish")
                 );
     });
}

This is my nuke script.
Instead of using MSBuld I have also tried with DotNetPublish and the exact same thing happens:
    Target PublishDotNet => _ => _
        .DependsOn(BuildDotNet)
        .OnlyWhenDynamic(() => Publish)
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            // Publish .NET Core project with the specified profile
            Console.WriteLine("Publishing .NET Core project...");
            var publishProfile = $"Publish-{Environment}";
            DotNetPublish(s => s
                .SetProject(DotNetProjectPath)
                .SetConfiguration(Configuration)
                .SetPublishProfile(publishProfile));
        });

I have also tried running command line equivalents of the MSBuild script and still it doesn't include my ClientApp folder in the publish. Only manually clicking the publish button seems to work.
In fact nothing is being published now. I don't know what is going on with this script.

In my publishing profile Publish-Staging.pubxml, the location I am publishing the files to is defined.
<PublishUrl>\\AcmeCorp.MyApp.local.com\Test</PublishUrl>.
When I hit the publish button manually it had no issues with this and published to the location just fine. However in my script I assume it extracts the properties of the specified profile and stores them as a string.
var publishProfile = $"Publish-{Env}";
...
DotNetPublish(_ => _
    ...
    .SetPublishProfile(publishProfile)

I found that if I manually set the output path to a local folder.SetOutput("MyApp/TestFolder")); it would work just fine, but if I set it to .SetOutput("\\AcmeCorp.MyApp.local.com\Test)"); there would be no output.
This is when I realised that the backslashes were causing the issue. Escpaing the backslashes solved the problem
Solution:
    ...
    string publishTarget = Env switch
    {
        "Staging" => "\\\\AcmeCorp.MyApp.local.com\Test",
        "Production" => "todo",
        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unknown environment: {Env}")
    };

    DotNetPublish(_ => _
        .SetProject("MyApp.Server")
        .SetConfiguration(Configuration)
        .SetPublishProfile(publishProfile)
        .SetOutput(publishTarget));
});

